# Query to convert an array to a map of documents with n attributes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm converting an array to a map in mongo.

```
  "items":[  
    {  
      "id":"AB-02",
      "qty":2
    },
    {  
      "id":"AB-03",
      "qty":0
    },
    {  
      "id":"AB-03",
      "qty":9
    }
  ]
```

becomes

```
 "items":{  
    "AB-02":{  
      "id":"AB-02",
      "qty":2
    },
    "AB-03":{  
      "id":"AB-03",
      "qty":0
    },
    "AB-04":{  
      "id":"AB-03",
      "qty":9
    }
  }
```

in the array version, it's quite easy to query based on how many elements inside `items`, but how do I do that with the latter format of `items`? as in, to query those documents whose `items` has lets say 7 elements?

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: my current version is 2.6

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to use MapReduce for this otherwise bump your version to 3.4.4 or the latest so that you can take advantage of the `$arrayToObject` operator in the aggregation framework to do the transformation. I have written an answer below just in case you would want to know how to apply the operator in your case and for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Upgrade to 3.6 and then make use of `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to achieve your result.

Comment: @RahulRaj Just curious, how does `$objectToArray` help to achieve the result in the above?

Comment: ahh my mistake, I was thinking of converting back and forth operation, nevermind, you only need one as you mentioned above :)

Comment: @RahulRaj No worries :) I thought I was missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MongoDB 3.4.4 and above, you can use the **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator that transforms an array into a single document and the array should be a list of documents that contains two fields, **`k`** and **`v`** where:

> The **`k`** field contains the field name.
>
> The **`v`** field contains the value of the field.

So you would need to create a pipeline that first transforms `items` array from

```
"items":[  
    {  
      "id":"AB-02",
      "qty":2
    },
    {  
      "id":"AB-03",
      "qty":0
    },
    {  
      "id":"AB-03",
      "qty":9
    }
]
```

to

```
"items" : [ 
    {
        "k" : "AB-02",
        "v" : {
            "id" : "AB-02",
            "qty" : 2.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "AB-03",
        "v" : {
            "id" : "AB-03",
            "qty" : 0.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "AB-03",
        "v" : {
            "id" : "AB-03",
            "qty" : 9.0
        }
    }
]
```

**[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** correctly does that with the expression

```
"$map": {
    "input": "$items",
    "as": "item",
    "in": {
        "k": "$$item.id",
        "v": "$$item"
    }                            
}
```

So your final pipeline can wrap all the above operators into a single stage with **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "items": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$items",
                        "as": "item",
                        "in": {
                            "k": "$$item.id",
                            "v": "$$item"
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```